# Iterate over key/value on map variable

Tags: terraform

In Terraform, I'm trying to build a SecurityGroup with a mapping for IPs and the comment associated. 
What I'm trying to do, is iterate over map Key value for the allowed network, and associate the map Value for the description field.

Code look like this,

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress" {
  type              = "ingress"
  (...)
  cidr_blocks       = "${var.ingress_cidr_blocks}"
  description       = "${var.ingress_description}"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.this.id}"
}

module "securitygroup-ssh" {
  source = ""
  (...)
  ingress_from_port = "22"
  ingress_cidr_blocks = ["${var.ipLlist}"]
  ingress_description = "${var.allowed-network}"
}
```

With this as variable,

```
variable "allowed-network" {
    type = "map"
    default = {
        "From Customer1" = "1.1.1.1/32"
        "Network this" = "10.0.0.0/24"
    }
}
```

Already struggle with map and lookup builtin function without satisfied results. Also being able to iterate through network as list, but the description field seem to be overwrite with the last value.

Any ideas ? Is this even possible currently in Terraform ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a map, but it should do what you want:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "ca-central-1"
    version = "~> 2.7"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "this" {
  name_prefix = "this"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allowed-network" {
  count = length(var.allowed-network)
  type            = "ingress"
  from_port       = 0
  to_port         = 65535
  protocol        = "tcp"
  description = split(",", var.allowed-network[count.index])[0]
  cidr_blocks = [split(",", var.allowed-network[count.index])[1]]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.this.id

}

variable "allowed-network" {
    type = "list"
    default = [
        "From Customer1,1.1.1.1/32",
        "Network this,10.0.0.0/24"
    ]
}
```